# c++ non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member with virtual function

Tags: c++, class, pointers, virtual-functions

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Enemy {
protected:


public :
virtual void attack(int ){


    }
};

class tank : public Enemy {
public: void attack( ){
cout << "attack from tank - " << attack << endl;

    }
};
class monster : public Enemy {
public:
    void attack( ) {
cout << "attack from mob - "<< attack << endl;

    };
};
int main() {
    tank tnk;
    monster mob;
    Enemy *enemy1= &tnk;
    Enemy *enemy2 = &mob;
    enemy1->attack(30);
    enemy2->attack(30);

};
```

I get an error saying

> non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member on every cout function.

I didn't specify my `int` in the virtual function, but when I try it, it throws more errors!

Comment: `attack` is the name of a member function.  Why are you trying to send it to `cout`?

Comment: what errors do you get when you actually override the `virtual` function? (e.g.: `void attack(int value)`)?

Comment: *i didnt specify my int in the virtual function*  -- Those functions are no longer "virtual" by leaving out the `int`.

Answer (score 3):

The `attack` functions signature in derived classes differ from the base class virtual function signature and as such they **don't** override the virtual base `attack` function. Make the function signatures the same in both derived classes and output the parameter to the standard output:

```
class tank : public Enemy {
public:
    void attack(int n) { // add the int parameter, now overrides
        std::cout << "attack from tank - " << n << '\n';
    }
};

class monster : public Enemy {
public:
    void attack(int n) { // add the int parameter, now overrides
        std::cout << "attack from mob - " << n << '\n';
    };
};
```

Also consider adding the [override](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier to both functions:

```
class tank : public Enemy {
public:
    void attack(int n) override { 
        std::cout << "attack from tank - " << n << '\n';
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to `cout` `attack`, which is the name of a function. Looks like you want to pass an integer to `attack`, but it has no parameters.

Here's how it would look with a parameter:

```
class tank : public Enemy {
public: 
    void attack(int i){
        cout << "attack from tank - " << i << endl;
    }
};
```